# Как генерировать числа с параболическим распределением?

Tags: алгоритм, математика, случайные-числа, теория-вероятностей

Помогите пожалуйста написать код следующего генератора. Есть некий диапазон генерируемых чисел от -60 к 60. Нужно, чтобы шанс выпадания числа ближе к центру диапазона, был выше, чем по краям, подобно параболе.

Comment: Нормальное распределение не устраивает?

Comment: Увы, это не то что нужно

Comment: *"написать код следующего генератора"* -- на каком языке? И какая задача решается, для которой не подходит нормальное распределение?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну, исходя из вашего требования и интегрального значения 1, плотность распределения имеет вид

p(x) = (3600-x^2)/288000

Дальше [рассказывать или и так понятно](http://stratum.ac.ru/education/textbooks/modelir/lection24.html)? :) Если рассказывать - то мне нужно немного посидеть над формулами, а вам уточнить - генерировать нужно целые числа или действительные?...

Ну, раз надо пояснить, и раз нужны целые числа - буду делать тупо, но просто :) Таких чисел должно быть 121, так что надо 121 интервал. Я не буду работать с обратной функцией, а сделаю методом интервалов. Можно обойтись 61 интервалом, исходя из симметрии, но проще сделать функцию распределения от -60.5 до 60.5, функция при этом будет иметь вид

p(x) = (60.5^2 - x^2)/295260.

Далее нам просто нужно посчитать интегральную вероятность того, что число попадает в интервал [m-0.5,m+0.5] (она равна 0.0123964 - 3.38685*10^-6*m^2) и создать соответствующий массив.

Язык вы не указали, так что извините, но буду на своем родном C++.

```
double p[] = {0.000203775, 0.00060681, 0.00100307, 0.00139256, 0.00177527, 
0.00215121, 0.00252038, 0.00288277, 0.00323839, 0.00358723, 
0.00392931, 0.0042646, 0.00459313, 0.00491488, 0.00522985, 
0.00553806, 0.00583949, 0.00613414, 0.00642202, 0.00670313, 
0.00697747, 0.00724503, 0.00750581, 0.00775983, 0.00800707, 
0.00824753, 0.00848123, 0.00870814, 0.00892829, 0.00914166, 
0.00934826, 0.00954808, 0.00974113, 0.00992741, 0.0101069, 0.0102796, 
0.0104456, 0.0106048, 0.0107572, 0.0109028, 0.0110417, 0.0111738, 
0.0112991, 0.0114176, 0.0115294, 0.0116344, 0.0117326, 0.011824, 
0.0119087, 0.0119866, 0.0120577, 0.0121221, 0.0121797, 0.0122305, 
0.0122745, 0.0123117, 0.0123422, 0.0123659, 0.0123829, 0.012393, 
0.0123964, 0.012393, 0.0123829, 0.0123659, 0.0123422, 0.0123117, 
0.0122745, 0.0122305, 0.0121797, 0.0121221, 0.0120577, 0.0119866, 
0.0119087, 0.011824, 0.0117326, 0.0116344, 0.0115294, 0.0114176, 
0.0112991, 0.0111738, 0.0110417, 0.0109028, 0.0107572, 0.0106048, 
0.0104456, 0.0102796, 0.0101069, 0.00992741, 0.00974113, 0.00954808, 
0.00934826, 0.00914166, 0.00892829, 0.00870814, 0.00848123, 
0.00824753, 0.00800707, 0.00775983, 0.00750581, 0.00724503, 
0.00697747, 0.00670313, 0.00642202, 0.00613414, 0.00583949, 
0.00553806, 0.00522985, 0.00491488, 0.00459313, 0.0042646, 
0.00392931, 0.00358723, 0.00323839, 0.00288277, 0.00252038, 
0.00215121, 0.00177527, 0.00139256, 0.00100307, 0.00060681, 
0.000203775}
```

Теперь мы просто генерируем случайное число в диапазоне от 0 до 1, и смотрим, какому диапазону оно соответствует (я буду по ходу дела суммировать вероятности, но это можно было бы сделать и до генерации, получив соответствующий массив, в котором на i-м месте стояла бы сумма первых i элементов исходного массива...

```
// Генератор случайных чисел
default_random_engine gen{random_device{}()};
uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0.0, 1.0);


for(; ; )
{
    double r = dis(gen);       // Очередное случайное число в диапазоне [0,1]
    int j = -1; double pr = 0; 
    while(r > pr)              // Пока оно превышает вероятность...
    {
        pr += p[++j];          // суммируем вероятность в поисках нужного числа
    }
    cout << setw(3) << (j-60) << " ";  // Это число на 60 меньше - потому что
                                       // нулевой индекс массива p соответствует
                                       // значению -60
}
```

Ну, а посмотреть полную программу с проверкой, как она числа генерирует, можно [здесь](https://ideone.com/pWeWLF).

Второй вариант - интегрировать p(x) от -60.5 до m+0.5, тогда получится значение

0.5061984917248075 + 0.012395854501117659*m -
1.693422746054325*10^-6*m^2 - 1.1289484973695498*10^-6*m^3, и код тогда принимает вид

```
double p[] =
{
    0.000203775, 0.000810585, 0.00181366, 0.00320621, 0.00498149,
    0.0071327, 0.00965307, 0.0125358, 0.0157742, 0.0193615, 0.0232908,
    0.0275554, 0.0321485, 0.0370634, 0.0422932, 0.0478313, 0.0536708,
    0.0598049, 0.0662269, 0.0729301, 0.0799075, 0.0871526, 0.0946584,
    0.102418, 0.110425, 0.118673, 0.127154, 0.135862, 0.14479, 0.153932,
    0.16328, 0.172828, 0.18257, 0.192497, 0.202604, 0.212884, 0.223329,
    0.233934, 0.244691, 0.255594, 0.266636, 0.277809, 0.289108, 0.300526,
    0.312055, 0.32369, 0.335422, 0.347246, 0.359155, 0.371142, 0.3832,
    0.395322, 0.407501, 0.419732, 0.432006, 0.444318, 0.45666, 0.469026,
    0.481409, 0.493802, 0.506198, 0.518592, 0.530974, 0.54334, 0.555683,
    0.567994, 0.580269, 0.592499, 0.604679, 0.616801, 0.628859, 0.640845,
    0.652754, 0.664578, 0.676311, 0.687945, 0.699474, 0.710892, 0.722191,
    0.733365, 0.744407, 0.755309, 0.766067, 0.776671, 0.787117, 0.797397,
    0.807504, 0.817431, 0.827172, 0.83672, 0.846068, 0.85521, 0.864138,
    0.872847, 0.881328, 0.889575, 0.897582, 0.905342, 0.912848, 0.920093,
    0.92707, 0.933774, 0.940196, 0.94633, 0.952169, 0.957707, 0.962937,
    0.967852, 0.972445, 0.97671, 0.980639, 0.984226, 0.987465, 0.990347,
    0.992868, 0.995019, 0.996794, 0.998187, 0.99919, 0.999797, 1.
};

...

default_random_engine gen{random_device{}()};
uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0.0, 1.0);

for(;;)
{
    double r = dis(gen);
    int j = -1;
    while(r > p[++j]);
    cout << (j-60) << " ";
}
```

Так мы получаем **точное параболическое распределение** генерируемых чисел. Просто же *"чтобы шанс выпадания числа ближе к центру диапазона, был выше, чем по краям"* можно получить и другими распределениями... Например, так:

```
default_random_engine gen{random_device{}()};
uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 60);
...
int r = dis(gen)-dis(gen);
```

Вот, [убедитесь](https://ideone.com/WCd9KR).

Так что данную задачу - генерации тем или иным способом распределенных чисел - надо ставить точно, без слов "*подобно*" :)

Comment: Перешел на вашу ссылку, жаль, что моих знаний не хватает, чтобы в полной мере разобраться с тем материалом. Поэтому прошу проще обьяснить. Я имел ввиду целые числа.

Comment: Ну, как мог - набросал...

Comment: а почему с обратной не стал? это же самый простой способ тут... хотя интегралы вставлять в ответ действительно геморойно...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Во-первых, очень геморройно - особенно для этой функции, во-вторых, этот способ мне кажется более простым для понимания... Впрочем, тут у каждого свое мнение :) А вообще, при такой нечеткой постановке задачи (*чтобы шанс выпадания числа ближе к центру диапазона, был выше, чем по краям*), так и разность (сумма) двух случайных сойдет :)

Comment: да уж... стало интересно, что там... вроде вывел, но в итоге вот такая монструозность получилась: https://ideone.com/oznhlF

Comment: @Fat-Zer Формула Кардано? :) Заинтересовали... Кстати, совсем по-хорошему, нужно вообще создавать какой-то класс типа `parabolic_distribution` :)

Comment: нуда... формула плотности для распределения `(-1;1)` `f(x) = 4/3(1-x^2)`... интегрируешь её от `-1` до `x` получается `F(x) = (x^3 -3x+2)/4 = y`, а потом находишь обратную функцию через Кардано... там 3 корня, так что надо выбрать подходящий... и это не `alpha+beta`... делается за 10 минту + 2 часа на поиск ошибок =))

Comment: *`F(x) = (-x^3+3x+2)/4`

Comment: @Fat-Zer  Мда... Корень-то там понятно какой выбирать, но что-то упростить эту комплексную хрень с налету не удается... :( Можно, конечно, попробовать интерполировать каким-то сплайном, но там края со слишком неприятной производной :(

Comment: @Harry Спасибо вам за подробный пример и объяснение

Comment: Если оно вас устроили - то почему бы не принять ответ, щелкнув мышкой по птичке слева от него?...

Comment: @Harry Не знал об этом, уже сделал